# PHP PDO Connections approach and MySQL aborted clients, aborted connects values

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

In a particular PHP - MySQL application i have been following a practice of creating and destroying the PDO connections from with in the public methods.

For Example:

```
public function updateCustomerNumber($customer_id, $customer_number){
                $conn = new database_class();        
                $sql = "UPDATE customers set  number = :CUSTOMER_NUMBER where id = :CUSTOMER_ID";
                $query = $db->prepare($sql);
                $query->execute(array(':CUSTOMER_NUMBER' => $customer_number, ':CUSTOMER_ID'=>$customer_id));
                $conn->disconnect();
                if($query->rowCount()>0){
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
```

So i have connected and disconnected the PDO Connection within the method. Database connect method:

```
public function connect() {
        if (!$this->con) {
            try {
                $this->db = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->db_host;dbname=$this->db_name;charset=utf8", $this->db_user,$this->db_pass);
                $this->db->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
                $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $this->con = true;
                return $this->db;
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                $error = $e->getMessage();
                echo $error;
            }
        } else {
            return $this->db;
        }
    }
```

Database disconnect method:

```
public function disconnect() {
        if ($this->con) {
            unset($this->db);
            $this->con = NULL;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I haven't come across any issue so far except that a in a couple of method i forgot to disconnect the PDO connection at the end of the script. However, I am not sure if there are any drawbacks of following this approach.

Reason i started questioning this method is when i check the MySQL global status values.

Aborted_clients: 32560
Aborted_connects: 128080

Going by the definition, Even If we don't close connection explicitly, PHP will automatically close the connection when your script ends.

What could be the cause behind these numbers? and is this approach of opening and closing a PHP PDO connections correct ?

Comment: Do you `closeCursor` before disconnecting?

Comment: May I suggest you to use an external library like [Doctrine DBAL](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal)?

Comment: @frz3993 I disconnect before returning anything from method. So every thing else with query data is done before closing the connection.